# Counting perfect powers using primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory

#### Result

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1}$

$n$ is by definition a  [perfect power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power)   iff
$\,\ \exists m,k\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}:n=m^{\,k}$

Let $N(n)$ be the number of perfect powers $\leq n$

We define
$$\mathbb{P}_n:=\left\{p\in\mathbb{P}: 
   p\leq\left\lfloor\log_4n\right\rfloor\right\}$$
It holds $$N(n)=\left(\sum_{\substack{p\in\mathbb{P}\\ p\leq \left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor}}\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt[p]{n}\right\rfloor-1\right)\right)-\sum_{k=2}^{|\mathbb{P}_n|}(-1)^{k}\sum_{\substack{P\in\left\{X\subseteq\mathbb{P}_n:|X|=k\right\}\\ \prod_{p\in P}p\leq\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor}}\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt[\prod_{p\in P}p]{n}\right\rfloor-1\right)$$

#### Question

After getting the result, I searched for mathematical language to describe what I did.

I found the following literature:

- [A counting function for the sequence of perfect powers](https://www.austms.org.au/wp-content/uploads/Gazette/2006/Nov06/Nov06.pdf#page=48) (Theorem $2$)
- [On the Distribution of Perfect Powers](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=b07703f1198ec04d25500994daab345bbd067cc8) (Theorem $5$)
- [Exact Formulae for the Perfect Power Counting Function and the $n$-th Perfect Power](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/83bf/fe52d2385ab003ccee302843b8ec80d3a8a0.pdf) (Theorem $2.2$)
- [Counting Perfect Powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3151506)

Overall, I found connections between my result and:

- [Prime omega function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_omega_function)
- [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)
- [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)
- [Möbius inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula)

I did not study mathematics, and thus don't speak the *language of mathematics*, thus didn't know any of the *mathematical things* I just listed before I searched literature.

**My question is** *Are there more connections?*

I already asked that question on [Matheplanet](https://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?topic=262716) (german) but didn't get any answers.
You can find more mathematical details over there.

#### Explanation

##### Lemma $1$

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a perfect power.
It holds $$\exists\left(m\in\mathbb{N}_{>1},\,p\in\mathbb{P}\right):n=m^p$$

###### Proof

Let $m,k\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}\text{ with }n=m^k$
$$\exists\left(q\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq1},\,p\in\mathbb{P}\right):k=qp$$$$\Longrightarrow n=m^k=m^{qp}=\left(m^q\right)^p$$
We define $$\hat{m}:=m^q$$$$\Longrightarrow n=\hat{m}^p\text{ with }\hat{m}\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}\text{ and }p\in\mathbb{P}\,\square$$

##### Lemma $2$

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ and let $N(n)$ be the number of perfect powers $\leq n$

It holds $$N(n)\leq\sum_{\substack{p\in\mathbb{P}\\ p\leq \left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor}}\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt[p]{n}\right\rfloor-1\right)$$

###### Proof

Let $m,k\in\mathbb{N}_{>1}\text{ with }m^k\leq n$

To maximize $k$ we need to minimize $m$ thus $2^k\leq n\Longleftrightarrow k\leq\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor$

Lemma $1$ yields that it's enough to consider $k\in\mathbb{P}$ to generate all perfect powers $\leq n$

Furthermore holds $m^k\leq n \Longleftrightarrow m\leq\left\lfloor\sqrt[k]{n}\right\rfloor$

Iteration over $k$ yields the result $\square$

##### Explanation of the $N(n)=\,...$ formula

Consider the sum:
$$\sum_{\substack{p\in\mathbb{P}\\ p\leq \left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor}}\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt[p]{n}\right\rfloor-1\right)$$
This counts how many perfect powers $\leq n$ can be generated by maximizing the value ranges for $m$ and $k$ and iterating over all possibilities with $k\in\mathbb{P}$.
Due to the fact that $m^k=\hat{m}^\hat{k}$ for $m\neq\hat{m}$ and $k\neq\hat{k}$ can hold true, we count some perfect powers multiple times.

The question is: By how much are we over-counting?
Let the prime factorization of $n$ be $n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_k^{a_k}$ such that all $p_{i\in\mathbb{N}_{\substack{\geq 1\\\leq k}}}$ are distinct.
Then, $n$ is a perfect power if and only if $\gcd(a_1,\,a_2,\,...,\,a_k) > 1$.
When we look at the prime factorization of the $\gcd$, the prime factors tell us whether the respective perfect power was counted multiple times.
Let $M$ be the number of times a perfect power $n$ is counted, which can be expressed using the prime omega function:
$$M=\omega(\gcd(a_1,\,a_2,\,...,\,a_k))$$
If $M>1$, we have over-counted by $M-1$.
The expression $\left\lfloor\sqrt[\prod_{p\in P}p]{n}\right\rfloor$ is crucial for compensating for the over-counting.
Since $n\geq 1$, these terms are always $\geq 1$ and reach the value of $2$ at $n=2^{\prod_{p\in P}p}$, the value of $3$ at $n=3^{\prod_{p\in P}p}$, and so on. They are thus triggered whenever an $n$ that has led to over-counting is reached.

Consider the sum:
$$\sum_{\substack{P\in\left\{X\subseteq\mathbb{P}_n:|X|=k\right\}\\ \prod_{p\in P}p\leq\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor}}$$
Note that $|X|\geq 2$, as $\sum_{k=2}^{|\mathbb{P}_n|}$ starts at $k=2$, so we only trigger for $M>1$ and not for $M=1$.
Thus, we iterate over all $k$-element subsets of $\mathbb{P}_n$ for $k\geq 2$.
The condition $\prod_{p\in P}p\leq\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor$ serves to stop summing $\left\lfloor\sqrt[\prod_{p\in P}p]{n}\right\rfloor$ which would only equal $1$, resulting in $\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt[\prod_{p\in P}p]{n}\right\rfloor-1\right)=0$.
The definition of $\mathbb{P}_n$ also has a stopping condition with $p\leq\left\lfloor\log_4n\right\rfloor$.
The smallest prime is $2$, and the smallest $k$ is also $2$.
It's about $\left\lfloor\sqrt[2p]{n}\right\rfloor>1$ with $p\in\mathbb{P}_{>2}$.

The only thing left is $(-1)^{k}$.
Although we've already discussed triggers, we've only talked about them being triggered, not about what is subtracted when they are.
When a trigger is triggered, the value of $k$ tells us by how much we've over-counted, which is $k-1$.
However, we have to consider how many and which triggers are triggered at the same time.
Using binomial coefficients, one eventually arrives at $(-1)^{k}$ as the "factor for subtraction" :)

From this, we realize that using the Möbius function, we can alternatively express the following:
$$N(n)=\left(\sum_{\substack{p\in\mathbb{P}\\ p\leq \left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor}}\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt[p]{n}\right\rfloor-1\right)\right)-\sum_{k=2}^{|\mathbb{P}_n|}\sum_{\substack{P\in\left\{X\subseteq\mathbb{P}_n:|X|=k\right\}\\ \prod_{p\in P}p\leq\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor}}\mu\left(\prod_{p\in P}p\right)\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt[\prod_{p\in P}p]{n}\right\rfloor-1\right)$$

Comment: Suppose $n = m^d$, and $d$ is the maximal such value. Then it can be seen that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\mu(n)(\text{is n an i-th power})} = \sum_{i | d}{\mu(i)}$ is $1$ if $d=1$, and $0$ otherwise. This means that $N(n) = n - \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor}{\mu(n) \lfloor \root i \of n \rfloor}$. This seems equivalent to your equation, once you take into account that $\mu(n) = 0$ for non-squarefree numbers, so they can be represented as a set of primes.

Comment: It isn't very clear what is your actual question

Comment: @CommandMaster Your formula for $N(n)$ is not equivalent to my equation. Your formula: $N(1)=1$ which is wrong.

Comment: you can say that $1$ is a perfect 0-th power (according to A001597's definition, for example) Your formula can be rewritten as $N(n)=-\sum_{k=1}^{|\mathbb{P}_n|}(-1)^{k}\sum_{\substack{P\in\left\{X\subseteq\mathbb{P}_n:|X|=k\right\}\\ \prod_{p\in P}p\leq\left\lfloor\log_2n\right\rfloor}}\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt[\prod_{p\in P}p]{n}\right\rfloor-1\right)$ and then it's the same as mine (after you separate the $i=1$ term) other than you subtracting 1 from the result of the root (which seems wrong, although I can't check right now)

Comment: Still wrong. Your new version of $N(n)$ yields $N(4)=0$ which is wrong. In other words: My formula cannot be rewritten that way. Note that in the definition of $\mathbb{P}_n$ we have $\log_4n$ instead of $\log_2n$. Furthermore did I give a definition of what a perfect power is, and by that definition, $1$ is not a perfect power. Please don't comment unless you checked your own results, thank you.